# "No -phase or -relationship specified" error when running dzil build

Tags: perl, dist-zilla

I am trying to build [this](https://github.com/jrockway/anyevent-subprocess) Perl module:

```
git clone git@github.com:jrockway/anyevent-subprocess.git
cd anyevent-subprocess
dzil authordeps --missing | cpanm
dzil build
```

But the build aborts with an error:

```
[Test] No -phase or -relationship specified
[Test] No -phase or -relationship specified at /home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/site_perl/5.30.0/Dist/Zilla/Plugin/Prereqs.pm line 162.
```

The `dist.ini` file looks like this:

```
name = AnyEvent-Subprocess
[@JROCKWAY]
[Prereqs]
Moose = 1.15
Event::Join = 0.05
JSON = 2

[Prereqs/Test]
EV = 4.0
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Prereqs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Prereqs):

> If the name is the CamelCase concatenation of a phase and relationship
>   (or just a relationship), it will set those parameters implicitly. If
>   you use a custom name, but it does not specify the relationship, and
>   you didn't specify either `-phase` or `-relationship`, it throws the error
>   `No -phase or -relationship specified`. This is to prevent a typo that
>   makes the name meaningless from slipping by unnoticed.

The `dist.ini` does not specify a phase or a relationship for the `[Prereqs/Test]` plugin, also the name `Test` is not a camel case concatenation of a phase and a relationship (as defined in [CPAN::Meta](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Meta::Spec#Phases)), hence `dzil build` throws an error to warn that the name `Test` is meaningless.

**Solution**:

Add a relationship to the name, e.g. `Requires`:

```
[Prereqs/TestRequires]
EV = 4.0
```

Comment: The other solution is to just specify -phase and -relationship options explicitly. But the Prereqs plugin often needs an alias either way so that you can use it multiple times for different phases.